# Как преобразовать коллекцию Laravel в обычный ассоциативный массив?

Tags: laravel

Сразу скажу: про `->all()` и `toArray()` я знаю, но тут они не подходят.

Вчера у меня возникли вопросы с преобразованием обычного запроса к базе с использованием `where()->get()` в XML. Соответственно, поскольку все существующие самописные преобразователи работают с рекурсивным обходом массивов - то что я использовал ранее - не подошло. На коллекции они не работают.

Я решил "собрать руками" XML, но уперся в то, что обойти коллекцию как обычный ассоциативный массив - не получается.

Например:

```
$xml = $cars->whereBetween('created_at', [$date_from, $date_to])->get();

foreach ($xml as $a) {
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) { 
        //здесь формируем XML-документ 
    }
}
```

не сработало и после

```
$xml->all();
```

или

```
$xml = toArray($xml);
```

Да, получается массив, но массив объектов.

В общем, вопрос такой:

- Как коллекцию Laravel преобразовать в обычный ассоциативный массив?

Спасибо.

Comment: Ты интересный человек. Пишешь, что тебе не подходит и знаешь о методах коллекций. Но точно описать, что тебе нужно получить в итоге - какой ассоциативный массив (и чем тебя не устроил метод `toArray` ты поленился. Так какой ответ ты хочешь получить? Посмотрел ли ты другие методы коллекций (`map`, `mapWithKeys`, etc...). Коллекция моделей содержит модели (капитан очевидность), которые также имеют метод `toArray`, возвращающий массив атрибутов модели. Проанализировал ли ты результаты своего запроса? И вообще смотрел ли ты в исходном коде (или читал ли в доках), чем `all` отличается от `toArray`?

Comment: А пробовали ли вы конструкцию `$cars->whereBetween('created_at', [$date_from, $date_to])->get()->toArray()` ?